# Is there a recycled ABS that can be used for injection moulded parts?

Tags: recycling, plastic

Also if there is how is it recoloured and does it have any properties that are not as desirable as virgin ABS ? This would be better for the environment and more sustainable because it reuses plastic rather than creating more plastic. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: @THelper a replacement

Comment: Ok, thanks for deleting the old question. BTW as long as there are no answers, it's perfectly fine to edit your own question and change its scope.